# Зачем в чужом коде тело конструктора вынесено в отдельный метод?

Tags: javascript

```
function A() {
    this._init.apply(this, arguments);
}

A.prototype._init = function() {
    // ...
}

let a = new A();
```

Не могу понять, зачем необходимо такое разделение? Зачем в теле конструктора вызывать другой метод в контексте того же объекта, если весь код, находящийся в теле конструктора можно поместить в сам конструктор? Какие преимущества дает такое разделение?

И еще. Зачем здесь вообще #apply()? Разве простой вызов `this._init(arguments)` не выполнит то же самое?

Comment: заодно уж пусть кто-нибудь объяснит смысл двух `this`-ов в  `this._init.apply(this,...`

Comment: @Igor только повторно прочитав понял, насколько это смешно

Comment: @Igor,  на самом деле вполне нормальное решение до spread операторов, с ним бы выглядело нагляднее: `this._init(...arguments)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось, всё дело тут в хорошо запрятанной документации. В StyleGuide'ах обнаружилась инфа следующего вида:

> Our pattern for writing classes is:

```
function Foo(arg1, arg2) {
    this._init(arg1, arg2);
}

Foo.prototype = {
    _init: function(arg1, arg2) {
        this._myPrivateInstanceVariable = arg1;
    },
    myMethod: function() {

    },
    myClassVariable: 42,
    myOtherClassVariable: 'Hello'
}
```

Чем такое решение обусловлено, ответить не могу. А решение впихнуть сюда `.apply()`, как подсказал в комментариях к вопросу @Grundy обусловлено попыткой воссоздать функционал spread оператора. К слову, движок (GJS), интерпретирующий код, позволяет использовать spread. Поэтому конкретно в этом случае использование `.apply()` ничем не обусловлено, кроме, судя по всему, разве что незнания автора кода о существовании такого оператора.

Comment: скорее не незнания, а давностью кода, когда движок, например, еще не поддерживал spread

Comment: а в этих StyleGuide не указано для чего/почему именно так?

Comment: @Grundy ни слова. Но я предполагаю, что это нужно для того, чтобы явно *подчеркнуть*, что код выполнится именно в процессе инициализации. Инициализации всего скрипта, я имею в виду. Данный код действительно выполняется всего раз (по крайней мере оно так предполагается).

Answer (score -1):

Первая функция - объявление класса и вызов конструктора, вызов любой его реализации. Вторая функция - конкретная реализация конструктора. Можешь унаследоваться и поменять её на другую. Apply и два "смешных" this'а нужны для сохранения контекста, просто так заменить не получиться - достаточно попробовать это сделать и выполнить код.

Comment: Как раз-таки тут вы ошибаетесь. Здесь обойтись без `apply` можно, и даже нужно. Метод `_init` *уже* вызывается в контексте `this`.

Comment: @smellyshovel, на самом деле без apply обойтись нельзя (если не брать в расчет spread оператор), так как передается неизвестное количество параметров

Comment: @Grundy Автор ответа ясно пишет, что `2 this'а нужны для сохранения контекста`, с чем я спорю. А с тем, что `apply` тут используется вместо spred'а - это вы еще в комментариях подметили, и тут я не спорю.

Comment: @smellyshovel, но apply как раз и устанавливает контекст для функции init в this, считай _сохраняет_ его в данном случае :)

Comment: @Grundy я понимаю. Но зачем повторять то, что уже сделано?

Comment: @smellyshovel, затем, чтобы передать в функцию заранее неизвестное количество параметров, для этого ее отрывают от контекста, и передают его напрямую вместе с параметрами

Comment: @Grundy да у нас тут диалоги о воздухе. Я говорю о том, что АО оказался неправ по поводу того, что в данном конкретном случае без `apply` в прямом его назначении (пусть это даже будет `call`) не обойтись. А вы говорите о том, что здесь без него не обойтись, если не использовать spread. Мы просто о разных вещам говорим :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65262/discussion-between-grundy-and-smellyshovel).